# How to use VBA to "transpose" a column of grouped data separated by blanks to rows

Tags: excel, vba

Since i find my problem hard to explain, I'll just provide an example.

This is the format of the data i have in excel in a column, separated by blanks.

```
A

B
C
D
E

F
G
H
```

I wish to transpose it so that the final result is:

```
A B F
  C G
  D H
  E
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You load the source range in an array, then you loop the array, writing each element to the destination, resetting the row and incrementing the column if the array element is blank.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Honorez's method:

```
Sub Honorez()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 2
    k = 0
    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, 1)
        If v = "" Then
            j = j + 1
            k = 0
        Else
            k = k + 1
            Cells(k, j) = v
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to select a range of column values to transpose?

Answer (score 1):

**Array method**

In addition to @Gary's-Student 's fine solution, I demonstrate another approach using a datafield **Array** and write back values directly to the new columns:

```
Sub Honorez2()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws  As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Honorez")
Dim i As Long, ii As Long, j As Long, m As Long, n As Long
Dim a()
' get data
  n = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & n)
  rng.Offset(0, 1).Resize(n, n - WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1) = "" ' clear prior values
' write data field to array
  a = rng
  j = 2                                           ' start column for results
  For i = 1 To n
    If a(i, 1) = "" Or i = n Then
       ' write data to new column
         ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, j), ws.Cells(i - ii, j)).Value = _
            ws.Range(ws.Cells(ii + 1, 1), ws.Cells(i, 1)).Value
       ' remember row and increment column counter
         ii = i: j = j + 1
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```